# File Path is exactly the same Windows Phone 8 MediaLibrary

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, path

I am trying to get all images saved in a Windows Phone device. I have saved Pictures from mediaLibrary in the list App.getImagesList(). While i iterate through the list i print the path of each image. In a collection of 700 images all files have different paths. Except 2 files with same file path. I wonder if it is possible...

```
 foreach (Picture pic in App.getImagesList())
 {
   // Print pic.GetPath() here
 }
```

Iteration:4
Path:C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Saved Pictures\PC090732.JPG

Iteration:5
Path:C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Saved Pictures\PC090732.JPG

Has anyone met this situation? Could it be an OS bug?

**Updated**

My output is based in system's extension method [MediaLibraryExtensions.GetPath(Picture)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.medialibraryextensions.getpath(v=xnagamestudio.42).aspx).

```
        var ml = new MediaLibrary();
        libraryPictures = ml.Pictures.ToList();
        foreach(Picture pic in ml.Pictures)
        {
            string path = MediaLibraryExtensions.GetPath(pic);
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide code for App.getImagesList() (or however you get the list of paths in the first place)? For something this simple it's usually much more likely there is a bug in your code than in the OS.

Comment: Also: What do you want to do with the path? There isn't much you can do with it, and you can't expect it to remain stable over time (eg, if user moves photos to the SD card).

Comment: Well my first goal is to auto upload new images, if user has checked this option. I want to find a way to recognize if new images are added to user's MediaLibrary. So i save the image path at first place. If i detect any new path this means something changed in user's Library.I don't mind if it is the same image. The server can handle this in the backend. The App.getImagesList is a list of images saved from the media library like this: var ml = new MediaLibrary();
            listPic = ml.Pictures.ToList(); The object saved in list is  Picture and has a native method GetPath().